# Adding Pages on One Note

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to add pages within Pages on OneNote. I have added a Certain Section and within that section I have a certain Page that I would like a page two, or another page within that page to where I do not have to add another page under the section itself....if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if that is what you meant, but you can create some kind of "subpages" in the sidebar, just like this example: "Chapter 1.2" and "Chapter 1.2.1" (the numeration to clarify). Just drag the page in the sidebar a bit to the right and it will automatically indent.

Comment: To better Clarify my issues: Ok I am creating a Training in OneNote for my  IT company. I have a section named Troubleshooting, within that section I have a page named Gaming I have multiple subpages with different games and how to resolve said issues. But what I want is to add more information in the Gaming Page but not to where its all clustered. I am needing to add a page 2 inside the Gaming page, rather than creating more subpages.

Comment: @Brandy Just like "tabs" inside the page? I'm sorry I do not know such a thing. Why are you using OneNote? Maybe there is such a feature, but probably I would have used other tools. OneNote is a great tool for taking and sorting notes, handwriting and other informations but creating complex structures is difficult

Comment: It a company site that is why we use OneNote but I was just wondering if it was possible lol but thank you for the advice